# CarrierWave: Uploading files to non-cloud server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file-upload, carrierwave, fog

I have looked at documentation for CarrierWave and even looked into the Fog documentation [here](https://github.com/fog/fog) and [here](http://fog.io/storage/), but I haven't seen any mention of configuring CarrierWave with or without Fog such that I could specify a non-Cloud server as the destination for all uploads.

Any ideas? I would like to ideally have a config like this:

```
 connection = Fog::Storage.new({
   :provider   => 'None',
   :root => '/home/media/uploads',
   :host   => 'storage.media.com',
   :username   => 'user',
   :password   => 'password'
 })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [carrierwave-ftp](https://github.com/luan/carrierwave-ftp). I think this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I am the Ruby developer advocate for the Rackspace Cloud and I would be happy to help you with any issue you have with our cloud.

The Carrierwave gem is designed to use a storage service like Rackspace Cloud Files as a backend. If you are interested in using a Cloud Server to host your files, you might want to checkout paperclip. I have used it in the past to save files to my Cloud Server and it works great. It also has the option to switch to Cloud Files at a later date.

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip

Let me know if you need any more help.

Comment: Appreciate it. I will contact you with questions when I get to implementing this for another problem set. However the application I am currently working on requires a media server on the local network, due to the lack of an Internet connection on a regular basis.

Comment: No problem! If you aren't attached to Carrierwave, I would checkout paperclip. I think it is just what you are looking for. (I do really like carrierwave as well.)

Comment: Unfortunately, we are attached to CarrierWave, otherwise I would be using Paperclip. :/